# how to check which JS function is executed using web tools for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wonder if it's possible to know which code is executed when I click on an element of the current web page in Firefox. The element does not show any [EV] pointer inside the web tool "Analyse page" panel, so I think that the event is managed in another way. 
Is there a way to understand what function in what script is called?

Comment: FYI, Firebug is no more.

Comment: You're right. I update my question.

Comment: The noobies' way is to put `console.log()`s in each function.

Comment: The page is not mine.